# Derivative of $x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$ not matching WolframAlpha result

Tags: calculus, derivatives, wolfram-alpha

I was calculating a very simple derivative of

$$
f(x) = x^2-\frac{1}{X^2}
$$

and my result is

$$
f^{\prime}(x) = 2x + \frac{2}{x^3}
$$

But I can't explain why [WolframAlpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20%28x%5E2%29-%281/X%5E2%29) the result is $2x$. It asserts that

> The derivative of $-\frac{1}{X^2}$ is zero thus
>   $ = 2x+0$

However, when you ask it to compute the [derivative of $-\frac{1}{X^2}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20-%281/X%5E2%29) alone, the result is $\frac{2}{X^3}$ as expected. Is there something I'm missing?

Here's my full solution.

$$\begin{aligned}
f^{\prime}(x) = &2x-(x^{-2})^{\prime}
\\
=&2x-(-2x^{-3})
\\
=&2x+2x^{-3}
\\
=&2x+\frac{2}{x^3}.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: It's because $x \neq X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify an expression for $f(x)$ and take the derivative, all other variables apart from $x$ are considered constants. Here, $X$ is such a constant that must not be confused with $x$.

When you submit the expression $\frac1{X^2}$ instead, there is only one variable ocurring on the expression andWolframAlpha tacitly assumes that you want to take the derivative with respect to that (i.e. apply the operator $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm d X}$ and not $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}$).

Comment: That was a very stupid typo, thank you. I'll accept your answer since it was the fastest one and upvote all the others (including yours), since all of them are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You did not use the same variable. Wolframalpha will make a difference between $x$ and $X$. It took the derivative with respect to $x$, so of course $\frac{d}{dx} X=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In your link at Wolfram|Alpha, you wrote $$ \dfrac {\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( x^2 - \dfrac {1}{X^2} \right), $$whereas you should have written $$ \dfrac {\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( x^2 - \dfrac {1}{x^2} \right). $$ Wolfram now thinks you want to take the partial derivative with respect to $x$, leaving $X$ as some extra constant.